# Declare style settings depending on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

Hey there Stackoverflow!

I got somewhat a tricky question and i tried to solve it by myself but hitting a wall recently. I am working with [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org) - a client/server side PDF printing framework in JS.

So i got a button linked with jQuery's [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which will append either a text area or an input field depending on the user's input and another button to preview and call a pdfPreview() function. Everything works smoothly and i wrote a function to get all the content and "give" it to pdfMake to create a PDF which then can be downloaded.

Now pdfMake got a style definition. (Example can be found: [here](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) but I am not sure when to declare the styles for the input the user gave me.

( My english isn't that great but i try to explain the working process step-by-step so you might follow me and understand my problem )

- User A inputs a headline and a text field with content
- He presses the button 'Preview PDF' which calls the function previewPDF()
- previewPDF() searchs for user input
- **NOW** if the user A puts in a headline pdfMake should give this content the defined style attributes from : defaultStyle
- if it is a textarea it should give this element the defined style attributes:
  textStyle
- After the function got all the content the user put in and declared the style for every element depending on **what** he put in ( i think it's an [object](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Object) but i am not sure ) it is saved to `content=[]`
- now i call the `docDefintion= {}` provided by pdfMake and say `content: content` and declare the different styles ( see codepen for example )
- pdfMake creates the pdf and gives the user a preview

Is there any way where i can say between step 4 and 6 "Hey this is a headline so remember to give this part of content the default styling settings later on" as "Hey this is a textfield input from User A so remember to give this part of content the textStyle settings later on"

I really like to work on this thing and it is really fun to see something working ( writing the part to get all the content was really cool ) so i am not exactly looking for a take and go solution but i appreciate every help i can get.

Here is the codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKrrBN

Edit: I totally forgot to tell = To preview the pdf in codepen please open up your console to see the dataURL. I don't know why it is not working with the iframe i created ( working on my dev webspace )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify style when you are pushing the content. Something like:

```
//yourcode
     contentFinal.push({text: contentText, style: 'textStyle'});
//yourcode
     contentFinal.push({text: contentHead, style: 'defaultStyle'});
```

And in your pdf template include the style tyes in an `styles` object something like:

```
 // Show Content on PDF
 var content = contentFinal;
 var docDefinition = {
   content: content,
   styles: {
   // Declare styles
   defaultStyle: {
     font: 'Roboto',
     fontSize: '50',
   },

   textStyle: {
     font: 'Roboto',
     fontSize: '1',
   }
   }
 };
 //yourcode
```

Demo codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqWjKg

Comment: Just checked the codepen. It works great! I will go in detail and check your solutions as soon as possible. Thank you very much for your time and effort!